# Ldap get dynamic values via PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

so i had used php to connect to AD using LDAP and i had successfully retrieved the data using LDAP-PHP connection...

my ad is like...
[image]

my code is...

```
<?php

// config
$ldapserver = 'ad.univ3.edu';
$ldapuser      = 'some';  
$ldappass     = 'some';
$ldaptree1    = "OU=TEST,OU=STUDENT,DC=ad,DC=univ3,DC=edu";

// connect 
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
if($ldapconn){
echo "Connected to ".$ldapserver.'<br /><br />';    
}
if($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

    // verify binding

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...<br /><br />";

        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $ldaptree1, "cn=*") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));


        $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

        //SHOW ALL DATA
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);    
        echo '</pre>';

                $count = ldap_count_entries($ldapconn, $result);

        // print number of entries found
        echo "Number of entries found: " . $count;
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

// all done? clean up
ldap_close($ldapconn);



?>
```

i got details in `print_r($data);`    but i get it in array...

i need like.. find all OU inside domain dynamically and get count in each OU(like users, computers, etc...) via specifying only domain..

i don't want to hardcode stuff like..

```
$ldaptree1    = "OU=TEST,OU=STUDENT,DC=ad,DC=univ3,DC=edu";
```

any ideas?? i can't get reference to do this as the information about LDAP is Generic...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am not sure what you are attempting to accomplish. If you want all OUs, you could query using a filter like: (ObjectClass=OrganizationalUnit) and store them in an array. The loop the array and determine the user accounts count for each OU.

Comment: i'm new to ldap.. i had seen the query for filter in ldap_search() but i can find a good explanation about how to use then.. say cn=* lists everything... but what is cn=* doing?? so i need to know explanation for different filters...

Comment: i want to list every OU and sub OU within the domain with its count without hard coding it... any idea??

Comment: If you want only users, rather than "cn=*" us (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))

Comment: it's nota bout users.. i need count from each OU/Container from the domain dynamically...